# The site can't display images

Tags: installation-profiles

My site can't display any images (logo, article's image) all type of images.

> [image]

Comment: Have you checked the image path in your browser ? using Firebug or another tool to inspect the code of the page rendering.

Comment: Debugging is the art of taking away all possibles causes ... make sure the folder where your images are stored have the right file permissions ...